# How to create threads and using the sleep function in linux eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, multithreading, visual-studio, sleep

I have a visual studio project which I am trying to switch over to work in eclipse in linux.  The project is written in C.

I don't know how to properly switch my project so that it works in eclipse in linux.  I also was wondering how to create threads and how to use any sleep type library function.  Basically I need the functionality of windows.h I think.

Thank you!

Comment: Use cross-platform libraries. For threads, use e.g. pthread, it has a Win32 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows and Linux have different APIs for things like sleep.  This article gives a good overview of some common porting conversions, such as sleep.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-MigratingWin32toLinux.html

Comment: thank you, I'll look into this and let you know if it solved my issues.